AWS SAM How to set trigger event for specific ALIAS
I have SAM template below
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: SAM Template

Parameters:
  Region:
    Type: String
  Account:
    Type: String

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      Description: 'TEST LAMBDA'
      FunctionName: 'TEST_LAMBDA'
      CodeUri: build/libs/
      Handler: com.test.TestHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: java17
      AutoPublishAlias: PRODUCTION
      Role: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${Account}:role/LambdaRole
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 900
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LOG_LEVEL: 'DEBUG'
      Events:
        KinesisEvent:
          Type: Kinesis
          Properties:
            Stream: !Sub arn:aws:kinesis:${Region}:${Account}:stream/KINESIS_STREAM
            StartingPosition: LATEST
            BatchSize: 10


After I deployed this template, the trigger by Kinesis is created. Not only my alias PRODUCTION, but also for LATEST part.
Can I only set trigger for only ALIAS PRODUCTION part?
